# Require/Backbone: load backbone overrides when backbone is called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im trying to do some overriding of backbone, something like so:

```
var newSettings { . . .}
var orig = Backbone.sync

Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    // updating options
    _.extend(options, newSettings)

    orig(method, model, options);
};
```

and use a module like so:

```
require(["underscore" , "backbone"], function(_, Backbone) {
    //if I call Backbone here, the sync override isnt applied...
});
```

Of course it doesn't work because it needs the global space so my question...

**How do I load overrides like this every time I request Backbone in a require module?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question, how do you call the original sync method?  If so, you're almost right.  You just have to change one line:

```
orig.apply(Backbone, arguments);
```

This will call the original method, which you've cached, and pass along all the same arguments, and specify the Backbone object as the `this` context.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my question is how to I call that snippet every time I use Backbone in a module

Comment: added some clarity to my question for you

Comment: You could create a module for your Backbone overrides called something like 'BackboneCustom' and have that module require Backbone.  Then, require your custom Backbone module wherever you are currently requiring Backbone.

Comment: I was trying to get around doing that. Seeing if it was a cleaner way to go about it.

Comment: I can't really think of another way but actually, I consider that quite clean and the best practice.  That's actually how Backbone plugins like Marionette work.